# How can I initialize a C# List in the same line I declare it. (IEnumerable string Collection Example)

Tags: c#, list, collections, initialization

I am writing my testcode and I do not want wo write:

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string>();
nameslist.Add("one");
nameslist.Add("two");
nameslist.Add("three");
```

I would love to write

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string>({"one", "two", "three"});
```

However {"one", "two", "three"} is not an "IEnumerable string Collection". How can I initialise this in one line using the IEnumerable string Collection"?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
```

Essentially the syntax is:

```
new List<Type> { Instance1, Instance2, Instance3 };
```

Which is translated by the compiler as

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("One");
list.Add("Two");
list.Add("Three");
```

Comment: I like this no-parentheses method, what c# version did that start with?

Comment: It's not *quite* translated into that, at least not in general. The assignment to the variable happens *after* all the `Add` calls have been made - it's as if it uses a temporary variable, with `list = tmp;` at the end. This can be important if you're *reassigning* a variable's value.

Comment: Automatic Properties and Object Initialisers were introduced with .NET 3 I believe, it's the same Framework version, just an updated compiler to support LINQ.

Comment: @Jon, Cheers, I never knew that part. :D

Comment: @Jon Skeet : "...This can be important if you're reassigning a variable's value." can you explain a bit more on this remark?

Comment: @Tony Consider: `list = new List<string> { list[1], list[2], list[0] };` - you don't want `list` replaced with an empty `List<string>` before the elements are added.

Answer (score 22):

Change the code to

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
```

or

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string>(new[] {"one", "two", "three"});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using the second line " List<string> nameslist = new List<string>(new[] {"one", "two", "three"}); "
when can we use it ?

Also what is meaning of  "new[] {...} " in the second syntax ?why new keyword is used along with the parenthesis [] ???

Answer (score 7):

Just lose the parenthesis:

```
var nameslist = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Comment: Oops, look like five people beat me to it.

Answer (score 7):

Posting this answer for folks wanting to initialize list with POCOs and also coz this is the first thing that pops up in search but all answers only for list of type string.

You can do this two ways one is directly setting the property by setter assignment or much cleaner by creating a constructor that takes in params and sets the properties.

```
class MObject {        
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Org { get; set; }
    }

List<MObject> theList = new List<MObject> { new MObject{ PASCode = 111, Org="Oracle" }, new MObject{ PASCode = 444, Org="MS"} };
```

OR by parameterized constructor

```
class MObject {
        public MObject(int code, string org)
        {
            Code = code;
            Org = org;
        }

        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Org { get; set; }
    }

List<MObject> theList = new List<MObject> {new MObject( 111, "Oracle" ), new MObject(222,"SAP")};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one way.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

This is another way.

```
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

list2.Add(1);

list2.Add(2);
```

Same goes with strings.

Eg:

```
List<string> list3 = new List<string> { "Hello", "World" };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"} ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parentheses:

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends which version of C# you're using, from version 3.0 onwards you can use...

```
List<string> nameslist = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work for int, long and string values.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(new int[]{ 2, 3, 7 });


var animals = new List<string>() { "bird", "dog" };
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 12 (.NET 8+) way is:

```
List<string> list = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
```

though don't use `var` with it, it needs to know the type since the new collection literals can be used for any kind of collection.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions